# Android Studio run Error:Android Source Generator: [jackpot] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: cordova, android-studio, meteor, gradle

I have a meteor cordova project that I was able to load on iOS emulator and android emulator but having difficulty loading it on the actual Android 6 device using Android Studio. When I try to run the app I get edit configuration pop up and if I proceed with run I get Error:Android Source Generator: [jackpot] AndroidManifest.xml file not found. Note I'm not sure why or if I need gradle, but either way to sync with gradle option I was not able to locate in Android Studio 2.1.2  Maybe someone can clarify why this is happening to me? [image]

[image]

Comment: did you `clean` your project ??

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: i tried meteor build > rebuild project and it says to 'Supply the server hostname and port in the --server option for mobile app builds. How do i find this?

Comment: visit this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/-dRnfg4Toqk

Answer (score 0):

After setting ANDROID_HOME and adding the tools directories to the PATH  . I was able to load the app into Android device with 'meteor run android-device" command. You can do this by adding these lines to your ~/.bash_profile file (or the equivalent file for your shell environment, like ~/.zshrc): These files are found in the /Users/[YOU]/ directory on your mac.